# jQuery click and toggle not working with class or ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys i'm trying to do a jQuery toggle on click of a link. Basically, show/hide a `div` on click of a link. It's not working when i put the class or ID, but it works when i directly put `a` in it.

Here's a link which has both ID and class.

```
<a id="gachlkx" class="gachlk btn btn-warning btnApply">@T("gaperfreport-apply")</a>
```

And a `div` which has a graph

```
<div id="gachwrap" class="chartsContainer">
   Contains Graph
</div>
```

Not working with ID -

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {                                            
     $("#gachlkx").click(function () {
       $('#gachwrap').toggle('slow');
     });
   });
</script>
```

Not working with class -

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {                                            
     $(".gachlk").click(function () {
       $('#gachwrap').toggle('slow');
     });
   });
</script>
```

Works only with `a`

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {                                            
     $("a").click(function () {
       $('#gachwrap').toggle('slow');
     });
   });
</script>
```

I tried all the  combinations. Keeping only ID or keeping only class. Doesn't work. Works only with `a`. Any solution?

Comment: working fine with `id` and `class` in fiddle

Comment: Sagar i think your error is localized to your code. try making a fiddle with the example. it seems your code is fine. are you by any chance adding the content to the page at later time maybe ?

Comment: @itsgoingdown - yes in fiddle its working. but not in the portal which i'm working.

Comment: Did you try change `$(".gachlk").click(function () {...});` with `$("body").on(".gachlk", "click", function(){...})` ?

Comment: the error is not in the code you show then. Make sure you have only one id call 'gachlkx' il all your page.

Comment: @aslawin - yes i've tried that combination as well. doesnt work.

Comment: @Alexis - yes that's the only one ID

Comment: Do you use a style template ? Make sure by inspecting the DOM that your link have the id ''gachlkx" when your page is loaded

Comment: Where do you apply jQuery into your code?

Comment: @Alexis - thanks for the clue. When the page is loaded, the class and IDs were being removed.

Comment: You're welcome. Search the new definition of id and class and use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a style template, some of them removing  id's and class.

Verify by inspecting the dom when the page is loaded.

**Solutions** :

Use the id / class generate by your library.

Or

You can try to include your own id / class with jquery after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Works well with class and id.

With id in this sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/9gydyb2o/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gachlkx").click(function() {
        $('#gachwrap').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

The error should be on other place. Have you checked the console log?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works fine if you have added anchor or div dynamically to DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click',"#gachlkx",function() {
    $('#gachwrap').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```